# How can I stop this image from stretching unproportionally?

Tags: javascript, css

Visit http://www.appsbayou.se

In Windows 7 (only tested in Chrome and IE11), the big jumbotron background image with the table and mac, becomes stretched unproportionally. However in Mac and in my iPhone the image never becomes stretched.

I haven't created this site, I'm to fix the bugs on it though, such as this one.

So far I've opened tc-scripts.js and messer around with the function CenterSlides() but it doesn't seem to help anything. Where is this effect coming from and why does it only break in Windows browsers it seems? Is it JS or CSS related?

How can I stop this image from being stretched?

Comment: What CSS rules are controlling the image?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an  tag then you can generally use this:

```
.someOptionalSelector img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

You can leave off the selector if you want that to apply to all images on your page/site.

If it's a background image you need to make sure you aren't setting the size to 100% anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has both a width and height set, however, it doesn't fit the image aspect ratio.
What I advice you to do is to set the image's parent div background-image to the image you want to display, then set the following CSS properties:

```
.carousel-image{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

What will happen is your image will be centered and cropped so it always is at least the same dimensions as its containing div.

Answer (score -1):

You can use width=100% and high=100%, or the percentage you need (e.g = half is 50%), instead of fixed values.

Comment: this or that, not both or it WILL stretch.

Comment: Instead of 

<div class="carousel-image slider-full"><img width="2022" height="500" src="http://www.appsbayou.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/coffee-iphone-macbook-air-166-2022x500.png" class="slide" alt="" /></div>

Try

<div class="carousel-image slider-full"><div id='carousel-image slider-full' style='background:url(http://www.appsbayou.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/coffee-iphone-macbook-air-166-2022x500.png)' class="slide"  alt="" /></div>